# How to compare and update millions of records in a oracle table?

Tags: sql, oracle, comparison, bulkinsert, bulkupdate

We receive a CSV file every day, with millions of records. Each record is identified by a unique Id.

Day 1, load the daily file in a 'Master' table. The structure of the table is the same file plus one more column called offset. Initially the value of this column is left blank/null.

Day 2 onwards, load the daily file in a 'Daily' table. 'Daily' table and 'Master' table are compared and the 'Master' table is updated as below:

a) Any record (identified by unique Id column) that is present in the 'Daily' table but not in the 'Master' table is added to the 'Master' table, with offset column value set to blank/null.

b) Any record that is present in both tables, value of 'offset' column in the 'Master' table is reset to 0.

c) Any record that is not present 'Daily' table but is present in the 'Master' table, the value of the 'offset' column in the 'Master' table is increased by 1.

At the end of the day, we have to produce 3 files and we can carry out the following activities to do so:

Create an add file for all the new records in the Master table. From the Master table, produce a file where offset column = null/blank.

Create a remove file for all the records in the master table where offset column > 100.

Create a cumulative file from the master table where offset column <= 100

Delete the records from the master table where offset column > 100.

There are some NFRs which is that cumulative file can have 20 million records and we have about 30 min to carry out the above exercise.

We want to avoid the iterative approach of using loops and preferably use some kind of bulk comparison and updates.

is it possible to compare the two tables and update them at the same time in batch ways. Can you help me with some SQL samples?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why dou you ask [exactly the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68623272/how-to-compare-and-update-millions-of-records-in-a-database-table) when it was closed before? Did you check this: [What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: @astentx: I rephrased the question so it is not an opinion question. I thought that was the reason it was closed first time.

Answer (score 1):

1. update all offset to 1

   update Master set offset = 1
2. update all offset to 1 for rows in daily

   update Master set offset = 0
   where id in (select id from Daily)
3. insert rows with offset null

   insert into Master (id, ... , offset )
   select (id, ..., null) from Daily

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to compare the two tables and update them at the same time in batch ways?

You appear to want something like:

```sql
-- Increment the previous offsets
UPDATE master
SET offset = COALESCE(offset + 1, 0);

-- Merge the two tables
MERGE INTO master m
USING daily d
ON (m.id = d.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET offset = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (id, col1, col2, col3, offset)
  VALUES (d.id, d.col1, d.col2, d.col3, NULL);
```